# Redirecting xargs input as stdin stream instead of argument

Tags: bash, sh, xargs

Sometimes it's useful to write an xargs command that begins with `xargs -I {} 'echo {} | [rest of command]'`  in order to redirect the argument as a pipe.

however, for large arguments, you will encounter `xargs: argument line too long`.

How do I tell xargs to redirect straight to the os input pipe for `[rest of command]` so that I avoid the above issue when using large arguments?

---

Reproducer:

```
# create a file with very long base64-encoded lines
seq 1 10 |
  xargs -I {} sh -c '
    openssl rand -base64 21000000 | tr -d "'"\n"'"; echo
  '> out.b64

# now, try to pipe each line into a new instance of a program
# xargs fails at doing this because the lines are too large
cat out.b64 |
  xargs -I {} sh -c "echo {} | rest-of-command"
```

Comment: I suspect you are using xargs wrong? you maybe want `xargs -I{} sh -c 'echo {} | [rest of command]'`

Comment: @Ben is doesn't make a difference. xargs will still give me `argument line too long`

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish here? The purpose of `xargs` is to convert input into arguments, but here you seem to be using it from input, to arguments, then back to input... which seems mostly pointless. What's it actually supposed to be doing?

Comment: @GordonDavisson well, for example, I'm trying to base64 decode a file with 100 json objects, of which contain a property that is base64 encoded (20MB per), so I'm using jq, and sed to extract just the base64 properties into a text blob, and xargs to simultaneously split the blob per-object, and execute the base64 decode.

Comment: I don't see how the pipe is working at all in your example. `xargs` doesn't run the command using a shell, so `|` has no special meaning.

Comment: Please post a [mre] that shows how you're actually trying to use this, we can probably find a better way.

Comment: It's also not clear how you're getting the "argument line too long". When you use `-I {}`, it doesn't combine multiple inputs into a single command. So the only way this could happen is if a single input line is too long to be a command-line argument.

Comment: You _could_ be using `xargs -I{} sh -c 'echo {} | ...'`, but that would be a major security problem (using string replacement in generating content parsed as code is a fast route to injection vulnerabilities), and there's no good reason to do it at all: in any scenario where it's useful, you could write code that achieves the intended purpose without any use of xargs at all.

Comment: @tuskiomi, _when invoked without going through xargs_, `echo` isn't subject to that limit because it's built-in to the shell rather than being an external command. So when you don't use xargs you don't have the limit in the first place.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy this security concern is out of scope for my application.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy xargs doesn't appear to be invoking a shell-intrinsic though, does it?  it appears to be running a binary (the shell), and that shell executes the intrinsic.

Comment: @tuskiomi, xargs _can't_ invoke a shell builtin, because it's not part of the shell. _The point I'm trying to make_ is that if you replace xargs with a shell function the whole command-line-limit-length becomes irrelevant.

Comment: @tuskiomi, ...anyhow: If you want a solution, it would be very helpful if you showed us a [mre] for the original problem you had _before_ you tried to solve that problem with xargs; that way we can figure out how you got to where you are, and what a more appropriate end solution looks like.

Comment: For example, I could imagine a problem for which the Right Solution is `while read -r line; do { rest-of-command ...; } <<<"$line"; done`. I can also imagine a problem where the right solution is `xargs printf '%s\0' | while IFS= read -r -d '' arg; do rest-of-command "$arg"...; done`, if you _actively need_ xargs to do unquoting and argument splitting for you. I'm having a _lot_ of trouble, though, imagining something where the right answer is `xargs -I{} 'echo {} | rest-of-command'`.

Comment: (BTW, word of experience: It's sound practice to assume that security and correctness problems are _always_ in scope. The worst data loss event I've ever been personally present for was a case where someone thought paying attention to details didn't matter because filenames "couldn't possibly" be anything but hex characters... until a bad pointer in a C extension to a Python library dumped random content into a string and caused that to be unexpectedly untrue. If you _always_ write code like it's going to be handling malicious data, then you don't get caught when that's unexpectedly true).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy here you are: `seq 1 10 | xargs -I {} sh -c 'openssl rand -base64 21000000 | tr -d "'"\n"'"; echo '> out.b64; cat out.b64 | xargs -I {} sh -c "echo {} | [rest of command]"` for my application, it would be `seq 1 100 [..]`, but disk space and all.

Comment: Thank you! Any objection if I edit that into the question?

Comment: None at all, thank  you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing you're doing calls for xargs at all, anywhere.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for ((i=0; i<10; i++)); do
  openssl rand -base64 21000000 | tr -d '\n'
  echo
done >out.b64

while IFS= read -r line; do
  { rest-of-command; } <<<"$line"
done <out.b64
```

The `{ rest-of-command; } <<<"$line"` could also be written as `printf '%s\n' "$line" | rest-of-command` or `< <(printf '%s\n' "$line") rest-of-command`. I don't recommend `echo` for the reasons given in [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo).

xargs is a limited-purpose tool: it transports content from stdin to command-line arguments. If that's not what you mean to accomplish, it's the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: BTW, in normal circumstances I'd avoid `out.b64` entirely and just pipe the two loops together, but bash's `read` implementation is much faster when the input source is seekable (which files are and pipelines aren't). If you needed that same speed while piping things together, I'd probably write a short tool in Python or Go to do the job; in the Python case it could even be inlined into a shell function. (Really, though, it might make sense just to reimplement the whole tool you're building in Python, soup-to-nuts -- JSON decoding, base64 decoding, etc etc etc).

Answer (score 1):

**Edited to include a better solution**

There's a better way of accomplishing what you're doing, and that's just to pipe it directly to the rest of the command inside of a `for` loop:

```bash
for x in {1..10}; do
    { openssl rand -base64 21000000 | tr -d '\n' ; echo; } |
        [rest of command]
done
```

No need to store it in a variable, dump it to a file, or read it out again.

However...

If you *do* need to read the string into a variable:

```bash
for x in {1..10}; do
    bigstring=$(openssl rand -base64 21000000 | tr -d '\n')
    echo "$bigstring" |
        [rest of command]
done
```

This is just unnecessary memory usage though. It also runs at about 25% of the speed of the first example.

---

*Old solution:*

Just replace `xargs` with a `while read -r line; ...;done` loop:

```bash
my-string-generator |while IFS= read -r mystring; do echo "$mystring" | [rest of command]; done
```

Setting `IFS` to an empty string prevents it from eliminating leading and trailing whitespace from the input.

You can also choose the record separator by using `read -d STRING` (in this case a NULL byte, `\0`):

```bash
my-string-generator |while IFS= read -d $'\0' -r mystring; do echo "$mystring" | [rest of command]; done
```

*Note: Using NULL as a separator is mostly useful for strict security when dealing with filenames; while exceedingly rare to see in the wild, technically *NIX filenames can contain newline characters.*

Comment: /me grumbles about `$'\0'` being actively misleading -- making readers think that bash supports Pascal strings that can contain NULs within their content, whereas it really uses NUL-terminated C strings where there's always exactly one NUL at the end. _Yells at kids on lawn, shakes cane at sky, etc._ :)